# evalf in sympy returns expression instead of value in single variable expression

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy to compute Taylor series, but something seems to be wrong.

I have an expression that looks like this (the first two terms of e^sin(x)):

`e**sin(x)*x*log(e)*cos(x) + 1.0`

but when I run evalf on it it returns the expression itself:

```
x=symbols('x')
print(sympify('e**sin(x)*x*log(e)*cos(x) + 1.0').evalf(subs={x:1})) 
# returns e**sin(x)*x*log(e)*cos(x) + 1.0
```

This happens regardless of what value for x I pick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `E` for the Euler number:

```
In [18]: x=symbols('x')
    ...: print(sympify('E**sin(x)*x*log(E)*cos(x) + 1.0').evalf(subs={x:1}))
2.25338076749345
```

Alternatively use e.g. `exp(sin(x))` rather than `E**sin(x)`.